# How to always work from a daemon and always reuse an existing frame? (bonus: do it with chemacs2)

Tags: spacemacs, frames, emacsclient, emacs-daemon, command-line-arguments

I'm new to emacs. I'm a spacemacs implant, really love ORG mode and evil mode. Been using for the past year or so.

I've read some of the *emacs documentation*, which is fantastically written. But I'm struggling with getting `emacsclient` and **emacs daemon** to work with a single frame.

I'm ok with scripting bash outside of emacs, but if there is an 'emacs configuration' way, I would prefer that - assume I'm clueless here.

### What I want to achieve

With a script named 'editfile' on my path, running:

```
editfile file-path
```

NOTE: file-path is optional.

I would like the following to happen:

1. If the **emacs-daemon** isn't running, start it up (with the
   correct chemacs2 profile)
2. If no frames are open, open `file-path` in a new frame
3. If a frame exists, switch focus to that frame and open
   `file-path` in the already existing frame.

I got #1 solved (with [chemacs2](https://github.com/plexus/chemacs2) no less), and I love it.

I need help with #2 and #3, Currently I always open a new frame, and I would rather it didn't.

My `editfile` script looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

MY_EMACS_PROFILE=${CHEMACS_PROFILE:-spacemacs}
MY_SILENT="/dev/null"
MY_EMACS_CREATEFRAME="--create-frame"
MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT="--no-wait"

# MY_SILENT="/dev/tty"
# MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT=""

if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then
  MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT=""
fi

function q_()  { printf  "'%s'\n"  "${@}"; }

function myemacs_full() {

  local _cli="$(q_ "${@}")"
  _cli="${_cli// /\\ }"
  _cli=$(printf "$_cli")

  _cli=$(printf "/usr/bin/emacsclient \ 
    --socket-name=$MY_EMACS_PROFILE \
    $MY_EMACS_CREATEFRAME \
    $MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT \
    --alternate-editor='sh -c \"( \
        /usr/bin/emacs --with-profile $MY_EMACS_PROFILE --daemon \
      ); echo ''Daemon started'' > $MY_SILENT; ( \
        /usr/bin/emacsclient \
        --socket-name=$MY_EMACS_PROFILE \
        $MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT \
        --create-frame \
        ${_cli//\'/\'\'} \
      )\"' \
    $_cli" \
    )

  2>$MY_SILENT eval $_cli
}

myemacs_full "${@}"
```

Here's what is going on there:

- I'm building a `_cli` command line which I then `eval`
- the `_cli` command comprises of calling `emacsclient` with the following options:

  - `--socket-name...` - the name of the server's socket. (That's
    because I use chemacs2, and more than one daemon might be running,
    this is the way to distinguish between them.
  - `--create-frame` - I would want this to be dynamic, and I'm trying
    to figure out how to determine whether this is required or not.
    Currently I always create a new frame.
  - `$MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT` will either be *empty* or `--no-wait` (text/terminal
    mode should use wait, GUI mode should not)
  - `--alternate-editor...` - If the daemon isn't listening, spin up
    the daemon and run the `emacsclient` one more time.
    The daemon is launched with *chemacs2*'s `--with-profile` argument.

    This is the main reason I'm using the funky process of building `$_cli`
    with `printf` and `eval`

### Update #1 : Things I've tried:

- [Tyler's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72372/38372) suggestion below
  isn't working for me.
  Where it fails for me is the need to pass `--with-profile=spacemacs` (or
  any other profile name) to the daemon. With the default, it is not passed.

### Update #2 : How `--alternate-editor` works

When an empty string is provided and the daemon isn't live yet, observing this with htop filtered on the string `emacs`, `emacs --daemon` is run, and if `--socker=<socketname>` is specificed, that parameter is passed as well.
Then the frame is opened, however, I did not see any new process.

To better understand what is passed to the *alternate-editor*, I wrote a very simple `/tmp/tst` script, and made it executable:

```
/usr/bin/env bash
echo "tst called with: [${@}]"
```

When I run `emacsclient --socket=spacemacs --no-wait --alternate-editor="/tmp/tst a b" -- --with-profile=spacemacs`, the output is:

> ```
> emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
> emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
> tst called with: [a b --with-profile=spacemacs]
> ```

The first 2 lines are expected, the last line shows what is passed to the alternate editor.

### Possible solutions (?)

The way I see it, to resolve this, at least one of the following strategies might work:

- Have the script above determine whether any frames are already open,
  and clear the `$MY_EMACS_CREATEFRAME` variable.
- Have something in the `init.el` that will make sure to reuse the latest
  active frame.

However, I have failed to figure out how to achieve either.

### Reaching out to the community for help

If you have a suggestion on how to do this, I'd love to learn.
If you think I am doing this completely wrong, I would love to learn of better/different ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Emacsclient reuses an existing frame by default. If you don't want to create a new frame, then don't ask Emacs to create a new frame - don't use the `--create-frame` argument.

Set `--alternate-editor=""` to get Emacs to automatically start a server if one isn't already running.

I think all you need is `emacsclient --alternate-editor=""`, the default behaviour should make your script unnecessary.

The available options are described in the manual section [emacsclient Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html). Relevant arguments for your use-case:

- ‘--alternate-editor=command’

> Specify a shell command to run if ‘emacsclient’ fails to contact Emacs. ...

> As a special exception, if command is the empty string, then emacsclient starts Emacs in daemon mode (as ‘emacs --daemon’) and then tries connecting again.

- ‘-r’

> Create a new graphical client frame if none exists, otherwise use an existing Emacs frame.

In the case of `chemacs`, it looks like falling back to `emacs --daemon` won't be enough, you need to specify your profile. ie., `emacs --daemon --with-profile spacemacs`.

That being the case, I think something like the following could replace your custom script:

```
 emacsclient -r -s spacemacs --alternate-editor="emacs --daemon --with-profile spacemacs" <filename>
```

I don't have `chemacs` installed, so I can't test this locally.

Comment: That doesn't work for me... it might be because I'm entering stuff into `--alternative-editor` - When I omit the `--create-frame` nothing appears.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You shouldn't be entering anything into alternate-editor, just `--alternate-editor=""`. It looks like you're trying something very complex to provide a feature that Emacs already does for you.

Comment: I need to pass `--with-profile=<profilename>` to the daemon, this does not pass that. Also, when I tried it just now without any special parameters, it opened the emacs frame in the terminal - not what I wanted either.

Comment: trying '-r' failed for me. My output of `emacsclient --version` is `emacsclient 27.1`. I'm running on Pop!_OS 22.04. In the page you linked I couldn't find the text associated with `-r`

Comment: See my answer for what I came up with: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72377/38372

Comment: sorry, the -r argument was added in Emacs 29.1

Comment: Now that makes a LOT of sense, seems that `-r` will simplify my script substantially. I'll check what's the upgrade path there - THANKS!

Comment: Found the relevant [commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-27&id=2bcc2160c9f7f16c5e9cd815b8074de27f30896d) - it's from Nov-2021. Now I'll check to see if I can get it on Pop!_OS without too much hassle as I don't want to compile Emacs from source. At least not for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably mark [Tyler's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72372/38372) as the selected answer, but I'm not able to test it, as that relies on a [commit from Nov-2021](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=id=2bcc2160c9f7f16c5e9cd815b8074de27f30896d), targeted at Emacs 29.1, which introduces a new switch `--reuse-frame`/`-r`. 
Currently Emacs 29.1 is not GA<sup>*</sup>.

The script below works as intended, but there is an issue with the way *Emacs* does this, and others have encountered this as well. See

- [Can emacsclient focus an existing frame?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54124/can-emacsclient-focus-an-existing-frame)

The problem is, although the frame gets the focus, it doesn't switch to the correct virtual desktop, so I'll need to figure an additional solution here.

### The Script

Replacing the script I had in my question, below is what I'm using now until Emacs 29.1 will be available. Luckily for me, I think it's a bit 'cleaner' than before:
([Link](https://github.com/Lockszmith/dotfiles/blob/main/_home/private_dot_local/bin/executable_edit-with-spacemacs) to my actual script in my dotfiles repo)

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

MY_EMACS_PROFILE=${CHEMACS_PROFILE:-spacemacs}
MY_SILENT=${MY_SILENT:-"/dev/null"}
MY_EMACS_CREATEFRAME="--create-frame"
MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT="--no-wait"
DEBUG_MY_EMACS=${DEBUG_MY_EMACS}
_cli="/usr/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=$MY_EMACS_PROFILE "

if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then
  MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT=""
fi

function q_()  { printf  "'%s'\n"  "${@}"; }

# This is needed for files with spaces and special chars
function prep_path() {
  local _cli_path="$(q_ "${@}")"
  _cli_path="${_cli_path// /\\ }"
  _cli_path=$(printf "$_cli_path")

  printf $_cli_path
}

$_cli --eval '(+ 1 0)' > /dev/null || {
  echo "Starting server..."
  2>$MY_SILENT /usr/bin/emacs --bg-daemon=$MY_EMACS_PROFILE -- --with-profile=$MY_EMACS_PROFILE
}
# At this point the server should be up and running, and so now we just
# need to see if we have any frames open
# If there are frames, we are NOT going to create a new frame, and so 
# MY_EMACS_CREATEFRAME will be set to blank.
[ "$($_cli --eval '(> (length (frame-list)) 1)')" == "t" ] && MY_EMACS_CREATEFRAME=''

client_args=$(prep_path "${@}")
[ "$client_args" == "''" ] && client_args='--eval "(raise-frame)"'
2>$MY_SILENT eval "$_cli $MY_EMACS_CREATEFRAME $MY_EMACS_NO_WAIT $client_args"
```

---

*  
I use [this](https://repology.org/project/emacs/badges) to track whether my repos have a desired version or not
    for Ubuntu flavors there is also [Kevin Kelley's Emacs stable releases PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs).